# File with @ in permissions

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, permission

I've done a bunch of searching and can't figure this out.

I have a bash file I am trying to create and run, but the file keeps getting saved with an @ in the last position on the permissions:

```
user@COMP Desktop % ls -l ./BASH.sh    
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  58 Feb 21 05:10 ./BASH.sh
user@COMP Desktop % xattr -c ./BASH.sh 
user@COMP Desktop % ls -l ./BASH.sh   
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  58 Feb 21 05:10 ./BASH.sh
user@COMP Desktop %
```

No, I have not tried running it under sudo and I will not. Otherwise, matter what I do, the file refuses to execute. Any guidance here would be appreciated. I am pretty sure the issue is that silly @ symbol in the permissions is the problem but even after an hour or so of googling and trying different solutions, I have not been able to get anything to work.

Comment: It needs more x.

Answer (score 2):

As I was typing this @nohillside's correct answer appeared first (`chmod a+x ./BASH.sh` should fix the issue). Still I'll add this bit:

Those "silly" `@` symbols indicate that there are **extended attributes** on the file. They have nothing to do with whether the program will execute or not. To see what they are (if curious) you can use

```
ls -lOde@ /path/to/file
```

or to see the actual *content* of the xattrs:

```
xattr -lx /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can‘t run the bash script is the lack of „executable“ permission. Run `chmod +x BASH.sh` to set the executable attribute (and `./BASH.sh` to execute it).